# Tqdm 4.28.1 in Jupyter Notebook "IntProgress not found. Please update jupyter and ipywidgets."

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, tqdm

I am trying to use tqdm_notebook in my Python code, but I am running into this error

```
import tqdm

for i in tqdm.tqdm_notebook(range(2, int(total_number)//20):i
```

ERROR:

```
IntProgress not found. Please update jupyter and ipywidgets.
ImportError: IntProgress not found. Please update jupyter and ipywidgets. See https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_install.html
```

I am using Python 3.7.1 and tqdm version (4.28.1)

Answer (score 124):

This worked for me.

```
conda install -c conda-forge ipywidgets
jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension
```

Restarting jupyter notebook afterwards worked.

Solution originally from [here.](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/issues/187)

Comment: Make sure these are installed in the environment the notebook is using!  I was running jupyter notebook from the base environment and selecting a different conda environment in the notebook.  This didn't work.

Comment: Installing this kills Jupyter Lab for me. Cells don't run and it disconnects from the kernel.

Comment: Update: I think that was a problem with the current version, ipywidgets 7.5.1. `conda install ipywidgets==7.4.2` fixed it.

Comment: In my case just running `conda install ipywidgets` was enough, there was no need for `jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension`

Comment: @JfredoJ , your solution worked out for me. However, the fact is that you should install ipywidgets to the environment in which your kernel runs; not to the one in which your jupyter runs.

Comment: @iliTheFallen why does it matter? Important is ipywidgets can be found, isn't it? In my case I installed it in the environment where I'm running jupyter, and I think it worked without problems... Perhaps your speaking from a logical / organizational point of view?

Answer (score 63):

For those not using conda:

`pip3 install ipywidgets --user`

Then restart the jupyter notebook server and reload

Comment: Also, don't forget to restart Jupyter Notebook's kernel after the installation.

Answer (score 12):

This works fine for me:

```
conda install ipywidgets==7.4.2
```

Comment: Alternatively, `pip install ipywidgets==7.4.2`

Comment: failed to install with Python 3.9. Conflicts found. Installed ipywidgets 7.7.0, the problem still exists.

Answer (score 6):

ah my bad ! Just had to install the packages jupyter and ipywidgets!

Answer (score 1):

I dont have enough reputation to leave comments so I just leave my answer here. I use python **3.11.5** notebook **7.0.4** and found this error. Initially I tried ipywidgets **7.4.2**, but the problem was still there, so I upgraded the ipywidgets to **8.1.0** and that solved the error