# DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found, importing tensorflow_datasets in python

Tags: python, tensorflow, ssl, import, tensorflow-datasets

I installed tensorflow 2.0 and tensorflow_dataset in a Python 3 environment.

then when i try to import tensorflow_datasets,

`import tensorflow_datasets as tfds`

this error appears:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I tried to install again tensorflow-dataser from Jupyter and not from prompt, and this error appears:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to solve the issue.

I did this by downloading and installing openssl from
[openssl](https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html)
(thanks to Udemy technical assistant)

but then, failed to load MNIST, so I should have updated jupyter and ipywidget with

```
conda install -c conda-forge ipywidgets
jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension
```

([the solution is from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53247985/tqdm-4-28-1-in-jupyter-notebook-intprogress-not-found-please-update-jupyter-an))

Answer (score 0):

I think your `cuDNN DLL` is not in `%PATH% environment variable` can you check it?
If not you have to add `cuda\bin` subdirectory to get Windows to find the DLL :)

Comment: sorry, I'm a little new in Python and I don't know how to check that. I don't know how add `cuda\bin` :(

Comment: Don't worry just google it like I found [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/installing-tensorflow-with-cuda-cudnn-and-gpu-support-on-windows-10-60693e46e781), follow these steps it explains all you need, its long blog and in section 5.3 explains how to check if you have environmental paths setup. :)